# Can you do blood-bond related activites without incurring blood-binding penalties with Tzimisce tricks?

Tags: world-of-darkness, vampire-the-masquerade

There is a certain Tzimisce power that allows you to take in foreign blood without incurring Blood Bond penalites - a combination discipline of Vicissitude and Auspex called "The False Drink".

From what I can discern, to learn an out-of-clan discipline (say, Protean), the student must find a capable mentor and drink one point of their blood, which would normally result in a level 1 Blood Bond.

Would The False Drink prevent the Blood Bond resulting from this procedure, or is it inevitable?

I would love to hear versions from both V20 and V5 on this one.

Edit: Based on Jadasc's answer, additional decomposition of the question may be required:

1. Is the consumption of mentor vitae necessary to being learning a
   Discipline from them?
2. If 1 is "no", can the mentor be deceived via The False Drink?

Comment: Your addendum is a little confusing, and would probably be better served as a new question. I don't quite get what you're asking there.

Comment: The "student must drink the blood of a vampire for whom the Discipline is in-clan" rule definitely applies for ghouls learning new Disciplines, but is it also the case for Kindred? I might be getting my editions mixed up-- is that a requirement that has changed between Revised, V20, and V5?

Comment: @Jadasc I believe he's asking if the full consumption (ie: being entered into the system) is necessary to learn the Discipline. To which the answer is: yes. Consuming the blood is an act to "start the mystical tie to the Discipline being
taught" (from V20). Therefore if you don't consume it (by using False Drink), you don't start the mystical tie and thus your blood can't develop the new discipline.

Comment: @CesarM actually... not for **all** disciplines. Or even most. "Basic disciplines" like Fortidude do not even need a teacher. Plus, there's *Assamites* who manage to teach disciplines among one another entirely without normal vitae drinking because *reasons* (aka: blood curse A or B doing either frenzy or damage)

Comment: @Trish It's been a while and I don't remember by head, but is this true for V20 or V5? This comment was about V20 from me

Comment: @CesarM For *basic* disciplins that was the rule in Revised Edition, but apparently that changed in V20 to *all non clan*

Comment: @Trish Makes sense then, version differences :) good to know either way.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### No, because that's not what "The False Drink" does.

"The False Drink" comes from V20's *Lore of the Clans*, and in the complete text, it explains that what the Tzimisce using this power does is fleshcraft a pocket to contain the vitae taken in—to be expelled later. "The compartmentalized blood is not absorbed into the vampire's system, and thus, the blood bond or Viniculum is secretly avoided." (p.242) Only on a failure do you actually take the blood in, and it says explicitly the usual consequences of that apply.

If you're ingesting the blood to learn a discipline, you need to absorb it into your system, so "The False Drink" won't protect you.

In V5, "Vicissitude" has been subsumed into the discipline of Protean, retaining only its fleshcrafting. Still, since this power comes from an Onyx Path book, it's unlikely to make its way back into Fifth Edition.